# Comparing dates in ascending and descending order in arrayList not working

Tags: sorting, date, comparator, comparable

I have an array of email objects. I need to sort them by two fields. the first field is by subject, which i have working, and the other is by date which I cannot get. I tried a bunch of other people's solutions but nothing seems to work. Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;

public class Email implements Comparable{

private String to;
private String cc;
private String bcc;
private String subject;
private String body;
private GregorianCalendar timestamp;    //time that email was created

//constructors and getters and setters (besides timeStamp) omitted to save space

public Date getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp.getTime();
}
public void setTimestamp(GregorianCalendar timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

//This works
public static Comparator<Email> emailSubjectComparatorAscending = new Comparator<Email>(){
    public int compare(Email e1, Email e2) {
           String EmailSubject1 = e1.getSubject().toLowerCase();
           String EmailSubject2 = e2.getSubject().toLowerCase();

           return EmailSubject1.compareTo(EmailSubject2);
    }
};

//This works
public static Comparator<Email> emailSubjectComparatorDescending = new Comparator<Email>(){
    public int compare(Email e1, Email e2) {
           String EmailSubject1 = e1.getSubject().toLowerCase();
           String EmailSubject2 = e2.getSubject().toLowerCase();

           return EmailSubject2.compareTo(EmailSubject1);
    }
};

//This doesn't work
public static Comparator<Email> emailDateComparatorAscending = new Comparator<Email>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Email o1, Email o2) {
        if(o1.getTimestamp().equals(o2.getTimestamp()))
            return 0;
        if(o2.getTimestamp().before(o1.getTimestamp()))
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
};

//This doesn't work
public static Comparator<Email> emailDateComparatorDescending = new Comparator<Email>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Email o1, Email o2) {
        if(o1.getTimestamp().equals(o2.getTimestamp()))
            return 0;
        if(o1.getTimestamp().before(o2.getTimestamp()))
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
};



@Override
public String toString(){
    return("To: " + to + "\nCC: " + cc + "\nBCC: " + bcc + "\nSubject: " + subject + "\n" + body);
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

}
```

here is the part of my other class, in which I call these sorting methods:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Folder{

private ArrayList<Email> emails; //initialize?
private String name;
private String currentSortingMethod; //default = descending 


public Folder(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    currentSortingMethod = "sortByDateDescending";
    emails = new ArrayList<Email>(); //instantiate the arrayList
}

 //omitted getters, setters and other irrelevant methods

 //This works
 public void sortBySubjectAscending(){
    Collections.sort(emails, Email.emailSubjectComparatorAscending);

    currentSortingMethod = "sortBySubjectAscending";
 }

 //This works
 public void sortBySubjectDescending(){
    Collections.sort(emails, Email.emailSubjectComparatorDescending);

    currentSortingMethod = "sortBySubjectDescending";
 }

 //This doesn't work
 public void sortByDateAscending(){
     Collections.sort(emails, Email.emailDateComparatorAscending);

     currentSortingMethod = "sortByDateAscending";
        }



 //This doesn't work
 public void sortByDateDescending(){
     Collections.sort(emails, Email.emailDateComparatorDescending);

    currentSortingMethod = "sortByDateDescending";
 }
```

I am really confused with this and I have tried so many different ways and none work. If anyone could explain how to make this work I would appreciate it greatly

Comment: What does your Email.emailDateComparatorAscending do?

Comment: I thought it would call the emailDateComparatorDescending method in the Email class because thats how I did it for the subject sorting which worked

Comment: Right! But i would like to see how have you implmented it. In order to debug it.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you need to see?